# Make a Pivot table in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

Im currently working on a worksheet, where I need to make some statistics over the data I have. I need to make a pivot table with VBA. After that I need to make a chart with VBA. I have the codes for both, and it worked earlier today, but somehow it is not working now. Can you please help me fixing the issue. I will mark where the issue is. Thank you

```
Sub AutoPivot1()

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache As PivotCache

Dim PvtTblName As String
Dim pivotTableWs As Worksheet

PvtTblName = "pivotTableName"

' set the worksheet object where we will create the Pivot-Table
Set pivotTableWs = Sheets("Delayed Students")

' set the Pivot Cache (the Range is static)
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Delayed Students!R1C1:R1532C7")

' create a new Pivot Table in the new created sheet
Set PvtTbl = pivotTableWs.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=pivotTableWs.Range("J1"), TableName:=PvtTblName)

' after we set the PvtTbl object, we can easily modifty all it's properties
With PvtTbl
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .DisplayErrorString = False
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .EnableDrilldown = True
    .ErrorString = ""
    .MergeLabels = False
    .NullString = ""
    .PageFieldOrder = 2
    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RowGrand = True
    .SaveData = True
    .PrintTitles = False
    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
    .TotalsAnnotation = False
    .CompactRowIndent = 1
    .InGridDropZones = False
    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
    .DisplayContextTooltips = True
    .ShowDrillIndicators = True
    .PrintDrillIndicators = False
    .AllowMultipleFilters = False
    .SortUsingCustomLists = True
    .FieldListSortAscending = False
    .ShowValuesRow = False
    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
    .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow

    With .PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With

    .RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels

    With .PivotFields("STUDYBOARD_ID")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

With .PivotFields("FACULTY_ID")
      .Orientation = xlDataField
      .Position = 1


End With
End With



End Sub
```

Comment: The issue is in the following code: Set PvtTbl = pivotTableWs.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=pivotTableWs.Range("J1"), TableName:=PvtTblName)

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. *VBA* and *pivot* is information that you've included in tags, which leaves *Issue with*, which is not useful. Your title should be descriptive enough to be of use to future readers who see it in a list of search results. While you're making that [edit], you can also add the **relevant** portions of your code in the question itself instead of burying it in a comment.

Comment: You've not explained any *issue* or *problem* ("it's not working" is not a useful problem description) or asked a **specific question** related to the code you posted. We want to help, but you have to do your part of the job first to clearly explain the problem and ask that question.

Comment: The issue is that I can't run the code. The code turns yellow. If I knew what the problems was I wouldn't have posted anything in here. I have figure out a very very long code, where on sentence turns yellow. What should I do before I poste a question ? I have read a lot of questions in here, it didn't help me, therefore I asked the question myself. My specific question is can anybody see what is wrong with the code.

Comment: *the code turns yellow* is (again) not a problem description. Neither is *I can't run the code*. **Why specifically** can you not run the code? Do you get an error message? If so, what is that error message? Again, we want to help, but **you have to do your part first**, which is **clearly and specifically explaining the problem and asking a question**. You've still not done so. This is not a site for *Here's a big bunch of code. Look it over and guess what my problem might be* posts.

Comment: Hi @DewanHansen and welcome to StackOverflow!  Thank you for the question, and for posting your code.  Quick troubleshooting question for you: What does your data look like?  Are all of the columns named?  If a single column is blank in the first row, excel won't create a pivot table.  If that's not the problem, could you post some sample data so people can play with your code themselves?